# The DNS is a liar?

Tags: dns

When I logged into a site I noticed that the DNS had sent me to a completely different site than usual. After observation, I noticed that there was a dot after the domain name, I remove it and then I fall back to the usual site. So depending on this final point but with exactly the same domain I do not arrive on the same site. If the question has already been asked, can you send me the page, otherwise explain or send me some links to understand.

Here are the links we are talking about: 
`https://feedback.minecraft.net`
`https://feedback.minecraft.net.`

Comment: And likely you are a victim of the resolver search list in the case where you don't use the trailing dot.

Comment: Would you be willing to edit the Question with the example URLs ?  I had never heard of trailing dots in domain names before... the link below looks like a good resource.  I suggest looking up the DNS records for both URLs outside of a browser.  
http://www.dns-sd.org/trailingdotsindomainnames.html

Comment: I'm a little lost because the site writes this well: "Try adding a dot at the end of "www.dns-sd.org", as shown in the subtitle at the top of this page, and you should still get the same page." So, are they the same or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a `.` at the end of a domain name.  But since it is always there, the only time/place you see it is when it is absolutely needed, like in a DNS zone file.  This dot represents the root zone of the DNS hierarchy.

```
ivan@darkstar:~$ nslookup www.ucla.edu
Server:     192.168.1.2
Address:    192.168.1.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.ucla.edu    canonical name = gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu.
Name:   gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu
Address: 164.67.228.152
Name:   gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu
Address: 2607:f010:2e8:228:0:ff:fe00:152

ivan@darkstar:~$ nslookup www.ucla.edu.
Server:     192.168.1.2
Address:    192.168.1.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
www.ucla.edu    canonical name = gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu.
Name:   gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu
Address: 164.67.228.152
Name:   gateway.lb.it.ucla.edu
Address: 2607:f010:2e8:228:0:ff:fe00:152
```

This is a nslookup I just ran against a somewhat random .edu domain.  The DNS server I'm pointing to is a instance of bind9 that does recursive caching for my local network, as well as a dns zone for my home lan.  As you can see, adding the `.` to the end of the domain still points to the same IPs, etc.

The only time you'll see the IPs change is if you are querying something set up for round robin DNS or some other load balancing method like multiple A records or the use of a CDN.

What you WILL get though are SSL certificate errors (unless a cert exists that also has the trailing dot), and possibly a wrong Named Host on a shared Apache server and possibly nginx or IIS or any other http daemon, but I only admin Apache set ups.  In the case of Apache, if a request is made to the IP using a name it isn't configured for it will use the first configuration file it parsed/processed on startup.

This is what happened in your case most likely, and this lead to a totally different website.

EDIT -

Having just looked at https://feedback.minecraft.net it actually is served up by zendesk via `minecraftfeedback.zendesk.com` which is round-robin DNSed to 5 different IPs in different subnets.

When you connect to that server using the trailing dot Zendesk hosting kicks in and it isn't configured for that name - Zendesk only knows about the `.net` version, not the `.net.` version.  So Zendesk throws an error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. A domain name always points to the same IP, whether it is a point or not, but if the DNS server has a bad configuration then it makes a bad redirection.... Thank you for trying to explain it to me, though.

Comment: @Tao the DNS is working fine.. the webserver(s) are the ones that aren't configured to deal with the trailing dot.  Folks who haven't taken a good networking class or configured a DNS server for a domain (zone) just don't know about the trailing dot...

Comment: So when I'm redirected to another site when I set up a point it comes from a bad configuration of the HTTP daemon or the HTTP client?

Comment: @Tao http daemon - "hrm, I don't recognize that name you are calling me, here's the content of the first site" or similar behavior.  I'm going to add more info to my answer for you

Comment: Thank you. What seems strange to me in all this is how the DNS sent me on the HTTP daemon? Why didn't it seem strange to the DNS. Why it is not the DNS that tells me this way of writing an address is invalid.... I'm lost here.

Answer (score 0):

> This server could not prove that it is feedback.minecraft.net.; its
>   security certificate is from ssl385002.cloudflaressl.com. This may be
>   caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your
>   connection.

It would appear Cloudflare had improperly configured its DNS/redirection for `https://feedback.minecraft.net`.

Comment: What do you mean? Why would Cloudfare make sure that we are redirected specifically to this site? How can he not have done it on purpose?

Comment: “How can he not have done it on purpose?” @Tao Because humans work at Cloudflare and humans make mistakes.

Comment: Try `curl -IL https://feedback.minecraft.net | grep location` from the command line to see the path of redirections.

Comment: Sorry, but it still doesn't tell me how they can accidentally point to an existing site?